# Realm, query for objects in realm using swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm working on a swift project and when I look around the internet in most cases you can query for an object like so:

object.objectsWhere("parentId = 1") or such.
However the objectsWhere func is not available to me, I can however use allObjects or allObjectsInRealm just fine.

The project is iOS7 in swift, working in xcode 6.3 beta Couldn't find the method in stable xcode neither if that matters. Importing realm through Pods like such:

```
pod 'Realm'
```

Any thoughts?

Edit:
object in this case could be the class extending RLMObject or a typealias of it in a generic func, but it's not even there without generics.

Comment: This method is declared in `RLMObject.h` (see [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/cocoa/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/objectsWhere:)).

Comment: I'm working in swift. Does this require me to do anything fancy to use it just like the homepage says? (Bottom) https://realm.io/

Comment: Note I'm trying to call this method on a class extending RLMObject

Comment: I don't see anything fancy at the bottom of the Realm homepage :) Anyway, according to the docs, if your object inherits from `RLMObject`, this method should work, so I can't help you further with this specific problem (I'm not an experienced Realm user myself).

Comment: Thanks for trying though. It's strange there are more methods which I cannot access, I can access objectsWithPredicate just fine though I'll stick to that then.

Comment: I hope you will find the solution. Don't forget to post it here if you do. :)

Comment: I will, but for now still using an alternative I'm not happy with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm uses Objective-C variadic arguments for the `+[RLMObject objectsWhere:(NSString *)predicateFormat, ...]` method, which aren't supported in Swift. This is why Realm offers a file which adds a few Swift conveniences ([RLMSupport.swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift)) which you can drag into your project.

Realm's installation instructions covers this and can be found [here](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/#installation).