# Generic method to get RLMObject in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to make a generic method to get an object model from a Realm Database.

The problem is, that the only way to call the method .objectsWhere is within a the **Model Class** ( not the instance ).

Is there any other way to make a generic method within model's instance ?

```
class DataBaseRepository {

// MARK: singleton declaration

class var sharedManager : DataBaseRepository {

    struct Singleton {

        static let instance = DataBaseRepository()

    }

    return Singleton.instance;

}// EndOf singleton declaration


let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()


// MARK: - addRLMObject

// For addRLMObject it works !

func addRLMObject( r : RLMObject? ) {

    if let objectToAdd = r {

        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        realm.addObject(objectToAdd)
        realm.commitWriteTransaction()

        return
    }

    println("Error addRLMObject \(r)")
}



// MARK: - getRLMObject

// This generate error : reason: 'Object type 'RLMObject' not persisted in Realm'

func getRLMObject( r : RLMObject? , reqString : String )-> RLMObject?{

    if let objectToget = RLMObject.objectsWhere(reqString).firstObject() as! RLMObject? {

        // I want to make a generic method to get RLMObject for all my methods
        // .objectsWhere is static method I can't call within instance

        return objectToget
    }

    return nil
}
```

}

Comment: Why is the `r` parameter not used in `getRLMObject`?

Comment: As I mentionned objectsWhere is a static method I can't call within an instance.

Comment: And I understood that. Let me rephrase my question then: why is there this parameter in the function if you can't use it? And what I mean is: either you're not using the right function signature, or you should be able to use the parameter in this function. :)

Comment: I was trying this `if let objectToget = r.objectsWhere(reqString).firstObject() as! RLMObject?`
But I can note invoke  `objectsWhere` with `r`

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29705155/2227743

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realm, query for objects in realm using swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692820/realm-query-for-objects-in-realm-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.dynamicType.classMethod()` to invoke a the appropriate class method, so in this case it would be `self.dynamicType.objectsWhere(reqString)`.

Comment: Thank you. But, it dosen't work. 
Error : `RLMObject?.Type' does not have a member named 'objectsWhere`

Comment: If you're getting that compiler error, my guess is that you're calling it on an  `Optional<RLMObject>` instead of `RLMObject`

Comment: No. It is because `'RLMObject?.Type' does not have a member named 'objectsWhere`. We have to call this method via the class model name. So, I can not make a generic method for all my class models